# Axial Vector and Vector Coupling Constants for General Quarks

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, collision, large-hadron-collider

I am studying particle physics and a bit confused about something.  The expression for the interaction vertex where a $Z$ boson couples to a pair of fermions is

$i \frac{g}{cos \theta_w} \gamma_{\mu} ( c_V -c_A \gamma^5)$

where the vector and axial vector coupling constants depend on the fermion.  This works fine if one is considering the interaction with a pair of specified quarks.  For example, for $u$, $c$ and $t$ quarks,

$2 c_V = 1 - \frac{8}{3} \sin^2 \theta_w,   2 c_A = 1$

and for the $d$, $s$ and $b$ quarks we have

$2 c_V = -1 + \frac{4}{3} \sin^2 \theta_w,  2c_A = -1$.

But what do you do if working with a real hadron collider experiment like the LHC where there will not be a specific type of quark either known for a collision of two quarks or production of a pair of quarks, what are the values for these coupling constants?  Do you add them up and take the average?

Comment: p and $\bar p$ are incoherent soups of up and down quarks and antiquarks, so you may, indeed, average them, if the valence quarks are what you are mostly interested in. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm just having a look at Standard Model Feynman diagrams and vertices for $q \overline{q}$ to annihilate to two gauge bosons and seeing if I can get a cross section (to compare with experiment the quark $q$ is not one specific type).

Comment: The input quarks are from the  first family only, u, d, and their antiquarks. What do you find for the average of valence quarks?

Comment: I find after taking the average if we assume only $u$ and $d$ quarks that $c_V - c_A \gamma^5 = - \frac{1}{3} \sin^2 \theta_w$ because of cancellations, does that make sense?

Comment: So I added what $c_V - c_A \gamma^5$ would be for the $u$ quark to $c_V - c_A \gamma^5$ for the $d$ quark and divided by two to take the average..

Comment: But there are *twice* as many us as ds in the protons of your beams.... You got to double the u pieces in the average (divisor being 3).

Comment: Yes you're right, so is it $c_V - c_A \gamma^5 = \frac{1}{6} - \frac{2}{3} \sin^2 \theta - \frac{1}{6} \gamma^5$?

Comment: That's a good start, depending on the nature of your approximation....

Comment: Should be squared absolute value, real.  Z amps don’t have this. Must ask separate, explicit question and delete this one.

Comment: I have posted as a new question.